# Parsing JSON String without separator using jq

Tags: json, linux, parsing, ubuntu, jq

I have a JSON string without the separator `,`. How do I parse it using `jq`?

```
$echo '{"access_token":"XXXX""expires_in":300"token_type":"Bearer"}' | jq -r .access_token
```

The above line gives me the below error:

```
parse error: Expected separator between values at line 1
```

I understand that the issue is because the JSON string provided is not comma-separated. But this is what I am getting as a response from the server. How do I parse such a string? I want to retrive the value for key `"access_token"`.

Comment: Why can't you fix the server to send proper JSON?

Comment: There isn't really any reliable way to parse broken JSON like this.

Comment: I am a consumer of the service and I don't have control to fix the server response @Barmar

Comment: Do they have any recommendation for how you're supposed to parse this garbage? You can't be the only one with the problem. If they're sending it, they should be able to advise you.

Comment: If you know the access token never contains quote characters, you can use a simple regular expression to extract it.

Comment: There's really no excuse for sending invalid JSON. There are libraries for every popular language that automate the proper formatting.

Comment: {"access_token":"xxxx-xxxx-xxx"} - how do i extract the value between 3rd and 4th quote ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression with `sed` if you know the accesss token never contains quotes.

```
echo '{"access_token":"XXXX""expires_in":300"token_type":"Bearer"}' |
    sed 's/"access_token":"\([^"]*\)/\1/'
```

The capture group between `\(` and `\)` captures the string between the quotes, and `\1` in the replacement string extracts it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two just-jq solutions, each with its own degree of brittleness. The first one attempts to convert each entire input line into valid JSON:

### Using `fromjson`

```
echo '{"access_token":"XXXX""expires_in":300"token_type":"Bearer"}' |
jq -rR 'gsub("(?<k>\"[^\"]*\")"; "," + .k )
    | gsub("{,\"";"{\"") | gsub(":,\""; ":\"") 
    | fromjson | .access_token'
XXXX
```

#### Assume the value is a string on the same line

```
jq -rR 'sub(".*\"access_token\" *: *\"(?<v>[^\"]*)\".*"; .v )'
```